# 'TimeGenerator' object has no attribute 'iso' when self.iso is defined. Shorter version of GUI does not print

Tags: python, tkinter

this is my program so far.

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class TimeGenerator:

    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        label_iso = Label(root, text="Isotope A, Element")
        label_vol = Label(root, text="Voltage")
        label_range = Label(root, text="Charge Range")

        entry_iso = Entry(root)
        entry_vol = Entry(root)
        entry_range = Entry(root)

        label_iso.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        label_vol.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        label_range.grid(row=2, sticky=E)

        entry_iso.grid(row=0, column=1)
        entry_vol.grid(row=1, column=1)
        entry_range.grid(row=2,column=1)

        button = Button(root, text='Time Range')
        button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
        frame.bind(button,self.calculateTime())

        self.iso = entry_iso.get()
        self.vol = entry_vol.get()
        self.r = entry_range.get()

    def calculateTime(self):
        x = 5

        self.iso.replace(" ", "")
        list = []
        for e in self.iso.split(","):
            list.append(e)

        f = open("/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/mass.mas12.txt", "r")
        i = 0
        while (i < 40):
            header = f.readline()
            i += 1

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            if (list[0] == columns[5]):
                if (list[1] == columns[6]):
                    self.mass = float(columns[13]) + float(columns[14])

        self.r.replace(" ", "")
        tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(","))

        list = []
        for q in range(tup[0], tup[1] + 1):
            y = x * math.sqrt(self.mass / (2 * q * float(self.vol)))
            list.append(y)
        i = tup[0]
        for time in list:
            print(i, ':', time)
            i = i + 1


root = Tk()
b = TimeGenerator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, I got an error message saying iso attribute doesn't exist. Meanwhile, the shorter version of the code (just to test things out) below:

```
from tkinter import *


class TimeGenerator:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        label_iso = Label(root, text="Isotope A, Element")
        label_vol = Label(root, text="Voltage")
        label_range = Label(root, text="Charge Range")

        entry_iso = Entry(root)
        entry_vol = Entry(root)
        entry_range = Entry(root)

        label_iso.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        label_vol.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        label_range.grid(row=2, sticky=E)

        entry_iso.grid(row=0, column=1)
        entry_vol.grid(row=1, column=1)
        entry_range.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.iso = entry_iso.get()
        self.vol = entry_vol.get()
        self.r = entry_range.get()

        button = Button(root, text='Time Range')
        button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
        frame.bind(button, self.calculateTime())

    def calculateTime(self):

        self.iso.replace(" ", "")
        list = []
        for e in self.iso.split(","):
            list.append(e)

        f = open("/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/mass.mas12.txt", "r")
        i = 0
        while i < 40:
            header = f.readline()
            i += 1

        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            if (list[0] == columns[5]):
                if (list[1] == columns[6]):
                    self.mass = float(columns[13]) + float(columns[14])

        self.r.replace(" ", "")
        self.r.replace("(", "")
        self.r.replace(")", "")

        print(self.r)

root = Tk()
b = TimeGenerator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

There is no 'no attribute' errors, meaning self.r does create the attribute 'r'. But still, nothing gets printed in the console, and I can't see why. Can you please help me out?

P/S: I just started python a couple of days ago, so even if there's some very obvious mistakes, they might not be obvious to me, so please be kind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
    frame.bind(button,self.calculateTime())
```

Instead, try:

```
    frame.bind(button,self.calculateTime)
```

In the first instance, you invoke `calculateTime` and pass the resulting value to `bind`. In the second instance, you pass a reference to the function itself to `bind`.

Comment: Thank you! I changed that and now it doesn't return an error anymore. However, there is still no answer printed in the console.. Do you know what else could be a problem?

Comment: After consulting [this doc](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and [that doc](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm), I realize that you shouldn't be calling `frame.bind()` at all. Delete the `frame.bind()` line and change your `Button()` line like so: `button = Button(root, text='Time Range', command=self.calculateTime)`

Comment: Now when I run the GUI, I get this error: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/TimeGenGUI/GUI/__init__.py", line 55, in calculateTime
    tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(","))
  File "/Users/LazyLinh/PycharmProjects/TimeGenGUI/GUI/__init__.py", line 55, in <genexpr>
    tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(","))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Entry for r was '1,12'

Comment: The line: tup = tuple(int(x) for x in self.r.split(",")) was from another StackOverflow post, so it shouldn't be where the problem is right? Could it be the interaction with Entry that is a problem?